# How to get Oppwa payment gateway live keys?

Tags: payment-gateway

I'm wondering how to get live keys for Oppwa. So far I've contacted ACI Payments Worldwide/Pay.ON, but I'm wondering if that's the correct way to get live. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ACI Payments Worldwide/Pay.ON is a service provider for payment gateway companies. You have to contact the related payment gateway.

For example, https://www.hyperpay.com uses that provider as I see their integration guides.